# How to access values in array in Laravel from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to access values inside array in Laravel with Javascript and those  values are in dropdownlist and I want to use onChange() method to influence the view.
The view code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Online Accounting</h1>
<br>
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'IncomeExpenseController@store', 'method' =>'POST']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
     {{Form::label('IncomeExpense', 'IncomeExpense')}}
     {{Form::select('IncomeExpense', array('Expense'=> 'Expense', 'Income'=>'Income'),null,['class'=>'form-control')}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('', 'Income')}} 

            {{Form::select('IncomeId', $incomes,null,['class'=>'form-control',,'id'=>'Income',  'onChange'=>'validate()'])}}
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('', 'Expense')}}           
                {{Form::select('ExpenseId', $expenses,null,['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'Expense'])}}
               </div>
<div class="form-group">
           {{Form::label('SumOfMoney', 'Money')}}
    {{Form::text('SumOfMoney', '', ['class' =>'form-control'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('Comments', 'Comments')}}
        {{Form::textarea('Comments', '', ['class' =>'form-control'])}}

        </div>
    {{Form::submit('Add', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

I want to access Expense or Income in above code for below code

Javascript code:

```
function validate(){
    var ddlIncome = document.getElementById("income");
    var ddlExpence = document.getElementById("expense");

    var selectedValueIncome = ddlIncome.options[ddlIncome.selectedIndex].value;
    var selectedValueExpence = ddlExpence.options[ddlExpence.selectedIndex].value;

    if (selectedValueIncome != "selectincome"){
        document.getElementById("expense").disabled=true;
    }
    else if (selectedValueIncome != "selectexpence"){
        document.getElementById("income").disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `else if (selectedValueIncome != "selectexpence"){` should be `else if (selectedValueExpence != "selectexpence"){`

Comment: @ErickRuizdeChavez, hi Erick yes you are right but don't you know how to access those array values in Javascript

Comment: at first glance your code looks good. I do not know how the HTML looks so I can't be 100% sure. Do you have a snipped I can use to play with?

Comment: @ErickRuizdeChavez, look Erick I have edited my question and added all my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I and doing some simple assumptions. Take a look at this example.

```js
var selector = document.querySelector('#selector');
var income = document.querySelector('#income');
var expense = document.querySelector('#expense');

function onChange() {
  expense.disabled = selector.value === 'selectoption' || selector.value === 'income';
  income.disabled = selector.value === 'selectoption' || selector.value === 'expense';
}

selector.onchange = onChange;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="selector">
    <option value="selectoption">Select an Option</option>
    <option value="income">Income</option>
    <option value="expense">Expense</option>
  </select>
  <select id="income" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="selectincome">Select an Income</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="baz">Baz</option>
  </select>
  <select id="expense" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="selectexpense">Select an Expense</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="baz">Baz</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Erick for your attention and for just great solution :)

Comment: sorry Eric one more thing, what do you think how can I ensure that if I select Income in the very first dropdownlist(IncomeExpense) then Expenses dropdown should become disabled. The same scenario should be with Expenses. I hope you will help :)

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. On this example, if you select 1 item from one dropdown the other one disables automatically. You can live test them by clicking on the Run code snippet button here in StackOverflow.

Comment: yes yes I have tested it all is perfect I just want to try in a bit different way. I will explain again if you look at my html code there you can see IncomeExpenses dropdownlist ok, then that dropdown has two values Income and Expenses as an array I hope you find them. Then, I want to ensure that if I select, say, Income then dropdownlist called Expense should become disabled I hope you understand it

Comment: {{Form::select('IncomeExpense', array('Expense'=> 'Expense', 'Income'=>'Income'),null,['class'=>'form-control')}} If I select Income then the below dropdown should become disabled {{Form::select('ExpenseId', $expenses,null,['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'Expense'])}}

Comment: Ah! I get it, there is an additional dropdown to select either income or expense. UX -wise I think it is an extra click not really needed, but let me update the example.